# Shiny: Add a plot to a column in uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am dynamically generating fluidrows for a uiOutput because the user selection will determine how many rows there are.  For each row, I have 3 columns - two are text and the third is a plot.

I've got the text working, but I"m struggling to figure out how to get the plot in there.

In the reprex below it's the same plot, but in my actual example I will need to use a table other than the one passed into map(), but filter it based on one of the .x values.

```
library(tidyverse)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("row_mt")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$row_mt <- renderUI({
    mt_list <- mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      group_split() %>%
      map(~{
        tagList(fluidRow(
          column(4,
                 .x$model),
          column(4,
                 .x$mpg),
          column(4, 
                 mtcars %>% 
                 filter(cyl == .x$cyl) %>% 
                   ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point())
        ),
        br()
        )

      })

    tagList(mt_list)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to create the plot with `renderPlot`, and then display it in the `renderUI` with a `plotOutput`.

Try this

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$myplot <- renderPlot({
    mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      group_split() %>%
      map(~{
                 mtcars %>% 
                   filter(cyl == .x$cyl) %>% 
                   ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
        
      })
  })
  
  output$row_mt <- renderUI({
    mt_list <- mtcars %>%
      rownames_to_column(var = "model") %>%
      rowwise() %>%
      group_split() %>%
      map(~{
        tagList(fluidRow(
          column(4,
                 .x$model),
          column(4,
                 .x$mpg),
          column(4, 
                 plotOutput("myplot", height=100, width=100))
        ),
        br()
        )
        
      })
    
    tagList(mt_list)
  })
}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The plot is specific to each row and so needs to be dynamically generated.

Comment: Yes, you need to do it as a list of  `output$myplots`  and use it in `renderUI`.  This is just an example for the first row.  I am not sure what you are plotting in each row.